# a bad feeling/bad feelings

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference between "I have a bad feeling about it" and "I have bad feelings about it"? Also, is it correct to say "I have a sense of foreboding"? I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: _I have a bad feeling about X_ means that (1) X is an event or circumstance in the future and (2) you are worried about X. _I have bad feelings about X_ means that, if X is an event or circumstance, it has already occurred, and that you have resentful painful feelings about it.  Basically, past and present tense versions.

Answer (score 1):

"I have a bad feeling about it" means that you have a sense of foreboding, or may simply be a poor representation of saying you've rationally weighed it and believe it likely to end badly.

"I have bad feelings about it" suggests you are emotionally involved with it, the "feelings" (plural) is essentially synonymous with "emotions" though might also include opinions or past experiences. It would not extend to a sense of foreboding.

Examples:
"I have a bad feeling about my mother" suggests I think she might die, or take the news of my marriage badly, or not show up tonight...I am predicting a negative outcome.

"I have bad feelings about my mother" suggests that I dislike her, or consider her to be generally unlikeable, I harbour negative emotions toward her or consider to possess certain character flaws for which I judge her.